# end date should not be greater then start date?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want end date should not be greater then start date. Eg: start date is 24/4/2017 and end date is 23/4/2017 in such scenario it should not allow to search it should be disable the calendar date 23/4/2017. Only End date 24/4/2017 onwards it should be enable

//this are the code in controller

```
$scope.formats = ['dd/MM/yyyy', 'dd-mm-yyyy', 'yyyy/mm/dd', 'shortDate'];
$scope.format = $scope.formats[0];
$scope.dateOptions = {
    datepickerMode: "'year'",
    startingDay: 1
};
$scope.max_date = new Date();


 //HTML code
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" style="padding-left: 5px;">
     <p class="input-group margin_zero calGroup">
         From<input type="text" class="form-control" name="dob" uib-    datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="ordersearch.startDateFrom"
 is-open="opened" ng-click="open()" datepicker-options="dateOptions" close-text="Close" max-date="{{max_date}}"  required/>
         <span class="input-group-btn newCalIcon">
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default calendarIcon" ng-click="open()" >
                 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
             </button>
         </span>
     </p>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-6" style="padding-left: 5px;">
    <p class="input-group margin_zero calGroup">
        To<input type="text" class="form-control" name="dob" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="ordersearch.startDateTo" is-open="opened1" ng-click="open1()" datepicker-options="dateOptions" close-text="Close" max-date="{{max_date}}" min-date="{{min_date}}"/>
        <span class="input-group-btn newCalIcon">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default calendarIcon" ng-click="open1()" >
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
            </button>
        </span>
    </p>
</div>
```

This is the code. I need to validate end date

Comment: Format your code please. It's unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

You should make use of `max-date` and `min-date` directive provided by bootstrap datepicker.

```
<input type="text" readonly="" uib-datepicker-popup="dd-MM-yyyy" min-date="minEndDate" max-date="maxEndDate" ng-model=""placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY"></input>
```

You can bind any dates from your `$scope` to these fields and the calendar automatically restricts the date after and before them respectively. For ex:

```
$scope.minDate = new Date(); //this restrict any older date from today
$scope.maxDate = new Date ( someFutureDateObject);
```

EDIT: If you are not concerned about max-date you can just skip it. Its not mandatory to have a max-date.

Hope this helps

Comment: Can you please elaborate in detail @saurabh

Comment: `max-date` and `min-date` are two attributes that the `uib-datepicker-popup` directive takes along with it. These two attributes tell the directive what is the min and max date to show in calendar.

Comment: what about (someFutureDateObject) mean?

Comment: This is the maximum date till when the calendar should be open. for example min date can be todays date and max date can be a date 10 days from now. In that case calendar will enable dates only from today to next days. All other dates will be disabled